# Exclude a property when returning objects from an array?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var users = [
    {name: tim, password: 123, connected: true}, 
    {name: jim, password: 345, connected: true}, 
    {name: kim, password: 678, connected: true, admin: true}, 
    {name: pim, password: 91011}
];

var connectedUsers = users.filter(function( connectedUser ) {
    if(!connectedUser.admin) {
        return connectedUser.connected;
        //not sure how to return the connected users object without the password attr
    }
});
```

The above returns all the users connected, this is to build an api for my app, only admin's can access this route and the passwords are encrypted but I would like to exclude them from the request. So how do I filter the object with an exclusion to password attr?

Comment: You don't want to re-create the object then you don't want to delete it from the original array.  So How about you duplicate the original array?

Comment: I am just confused at this point lol

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` is for filtering entries; ie, if you return true for an entry it is included in the results, otherwise it's dropped. As such, you can't use `filter()` to transform the input. Instead, you should `map` the filtered results to objects without the passpword:

```js
var users = [
    {name: 'tim', password: '123', connected: true}, 
    {name: 'jim', password: '345', connected: true}, 
    {name: 'kim', password: '678', connected: true, admin: true}, 
    {name: 'pim', password: '91011'}
];
users.filter(function( connectedUser ) {
    return !connectedUser.admin && connectedUser.connected;
}).map(function(user) {
    // return {name: user.name, connected: user.connected}
    // __OR__
    // EDIT1: You can as the following to delete only one
    // field if the user object is very large. You can also
    // use JQuery's clone() method instead of stringify/parse.
    userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))
    delete userCopy.password
    return userCopy
})
```

PS. I made a tiny change to your filter function.

Comment: Why because I need to pass that object into the `res.json`? I like it but there has to be an easier way to exclude just the password because in my real code I am sending a lot of properties and don't want to map each one. Other than that thanks.

Comment: You can simply clone your object and delete the password, if you have many properties to include. See the comments I added in the code

Comment: If you only want to delete a field among 100 other properties, you need to create a copy of your user object and then delete the password property. Otherwise, you'll delete a field from your original array. `  userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))` copies the object for you. And then you delete the password and return the modified copy (that does not have a password in it)

Comment: Ah it makes sense, a lot of things going on right now, I appreciate the time taken and I am sure this is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** filtered array removing password from each element. You can do it by creating a new use object without password property:

```
var connectedUsers = users.filter(function(user) {
    // ...
})
.map(function(user) {
    var newUser = {}, key;
    for (key in user) {
        if (key !== 'password') {
            newUser[key] = user[key];
        }
    }
    return newUser;
});
```

Comment: so use .map instead of filter?

Comment: No, use use filter like you are doing right now, and then chain .map to results of the filter.

Comment: ah okay never used map before trying it now

Comment: That would modify the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the password attribute of each user using

```
delete connectedUser.password;
```

Comment: But, it'll delete password from the original array.

Comment: I guess that is not a problem, unless he'll be persisting the array after return a list of connected users (which is not impossiple but a bit strange)

Comment: No the password only needs to stay in the database, I am using mongodb to grab all the users in the db and filter the user models that are connected. So pretty much creating a new object from an object in the database. Do I put this before I return or what?

Comment: I tried it like `if(!currentUser.admin) {
                            delete currentUser.password;
                            return currentUser.connected;
                        }` and still get password returned in the api

Comment: Oh, I see, why don't you just write this logic as a db query?, if not, after you have the connectedUsers array go throug the items and delete the password, but still, the db query will be a much cleaner and safer way of doing this

Comment: Ah I went through the mongodb docs, and could not figure out a way to exclude the password. Ill go back into that.